# ERROR: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. - Trying to deploy react docker image to AWS ECR to run on Fargate

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am new to AWS and React. I am trying to deploy a react docker image to AWS ECR to run on Fargate. There is also an ALB that points to the ECS service. In the ECS console task is running. However when I go the ALB URL on my browser, the page is white(empty). In the DOM, I see this element

`<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>`

**What I have tried so far:**

- adding those to the package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
"homepage": "."
```

- changing manifest.json

from

`"start_url": ".",`

to

`"start_url": "/",`

I also tried different dockerfiles and currently I am using this:

```
# Stage 1: Build the React application
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:17-alpine3.14 AS build

WORKDIR /app

# Set environment path
ENV PATH="/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve the React application from Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the react build from Stage 1
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Custom nginc.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port 80 to the host
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Note: Javascript is enabled on my browser. I tried both enabled and disabled. Still same.

Can you help me to fix this problem so I can see my deployed react page?

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong thing. That `<noscript>` tag is just there for people who don't have JavaScript enabled, it will actually show that message in the web browser to them. You aren't seeing that message in the web browser, so that's not the issue. You need to look in the browser's developer tools Network tab, to see if there are any network requests failing.

Comment: When I check the network section, I see that there is no manifest.json, main.xxxxx.js and main.xxxxxx.css. However, when I build the react app on my local, I can see them in my build folder. I think something makes them unreachable when I build the docker image but I don't know what. Thank you for your answer.